# How to configure DNS on Mobile Broadband Interface using command-prompt on Windows 8?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8, dns, mobile-broadband

I am using a HSPA USB modem which has two different modes. One which lets you install modem driver/software, and other which enables Mobile Broadband Interface on Windows.

It's possible to set DNS using GUI, but want to do it using Command Prompt without changing IP, subnet or gateway.

DNS setting changes after every time I reconnect. I receives new settings from ISP.

Tried everything, seems impossible on Windows.

Comment: It may be possible if your modem supports a telnet interface. There is not enough information in your question to answer.

Comment: @DavidPostill It's a USB dongle/stick, what new information should I add? Didn't get you. PS - I don't think it has telnet interface.

Comment: @DavidPostill It is same as enabling 'Mobile Data' on android phone and adding ISP's APN (Access Point) for accessing GSM, GPRS, 2G, 3G, 4G.

Comment: See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18620173/how-can-i-set-change-dns-using-the-command-prompt-at-windows-8) on using commands such as `netsh interface ipv4 add dnsserver "Ethernet" 8.8.8.8 index=1`. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @harrymc That worked! I think I tried that command once but got the syntax wrong. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detailed information can be found in the post
[How can I set / change DNS using the command-prompt at windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18620173/how-can-i-set-change-dns-using-the-command-prompt-at-windows-8),
which I summarize below :

First, find the network interface name by entering in the Command Prompt :

```
netsh interface show interface
```

This may show something like :

```
Admin State    State          Type             Interface Name
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Enabled        Connected      Dedicated        Local Area Connection
```

To change the DNS server to Google, enter :

```
netsh interface ipv4 add dnsserver "Local Area Connection" 8.8.8.8 index=1
```

This will set the Google DNS server as the first DNS server in the list of DNS servers for the interface.

To reset the interface back to DHCP enter :

```
netsh interface ipv4 set address name="Local Area Connection" dhcp
```

For more information see :

- [Netsh commands for Interface IP](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738592%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)
- [Cool Things to Do with Netsh](http://windowsitpro.com/windows-server/cool-things-do-netsh)

Comment: `netsh interface show interface` won't work on Mobile Broadband interfaces (at least it didn't work for me), you will have to do `netsh mbn show interfaces`.

Comment: @mark-evans `netsh interface show interface` won't work for me either .. but your new command doesn't work and shows the error `The following command was not found: mbn show interfaces`